# How to fix 'WKWebViewManager.evaluateJavaScript is not a function

Tags: ios, react-native, wkwebview, expo, react-native-ios

I'm working on a React Native app, from **Expo**. I ejected the project to ExpoKit and added **react-native-wkwebview-reborn**. I'm facing some issues with this library as always appear this error:

[image]

Here is my code: 
ContentWebView.ios.js

```
render() {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <WKWebView
          ref={WEBVIEW_REF}
          sendCookies={true}
          style={styles.webview}
          source={{uri: this.props.url}}
          allowsLinkPreview={false}
          onMessage={(e) => this._handleMessage(e)}
          onNavigationStateChange={(e) => this._onNavigationStateChange(e)}
      />
```

and here is where my app crashes :

```
_onNavigationStateChange(e) {
    this.refs[WEBVIEW_REF].evaluateJavaScript('window.postMessage({cookies: document.cookie}); clearInterval(window.myCartInterval); window.myCartInterval = setInterval(function(){window.postMessage({cookies: document.cookie});},5000);');
  }
```

If you have any idea it would be so useful! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try change code??

Try it this way.

```js
   <WKWebView
          ref={WEBVIEW_REF => {this.webview = WEBVIEW_REF;}}
          sendCookies={true}
          style={styles.webview}
          source={{uri: this.props.url}}
          allowsLinkPreview={false}
          onMessage={(e) => this._handleMessage(e)}
          onNavigationStateChange={(e) => this._onNavigationStateChange(e)}
      />
...
_onNavigationStateChange(e) {
    this.webview.evaluateJavaScript('window.postMessage(e)');
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

The function is named injectJavaScript in React Native